# Heroku throws an error like "Push rejected, Unauthorized access."

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm using [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) for code commits, and that Git URL integrate to Heroku for deployment. I have done it many times, and every time it works, but now this time I got an error:

> Push rejected, Unauthorized access

I'm using Node.js. as the back-end. Here is my `package.json` file (email replaced):

```
{
 "name": "wrapperdemo",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Payment Gatway demo",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node app.js"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "~4.13.3",
"node-libcurl": "*",
"node-jquery-param": "*",
"xml2js": "^0.4.17"
},
"author": "Gunjan <my-email@example.com>",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

ERROR:

[image]

Comment: Heroku is having issues with builds. Please check https://status.heroku.com/incidents/977

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it's an error currently being investigated, recognised as of Nov 6 2016, 08:48 UTC — see [here](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/977)

---

This error was considered resolved at 09:37 UTC the same date.

Comment: Seems to be working for me now (11/6/2016, 09.30 UTC)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with my node.js app. I fixed it by removing the .gitignore file and it worked again!

Better wait for Heroku feedback on that issue.

Comment: I am downvoting this because the .gitignore file does not appear to have been the cause of this incident (it was a temporary bug), and it would be unfortunate for future visitors to think "delete your gitignore" solves an authentication issue.